# Importing .csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, visual-studio-code, import

I'm trying to import a .csv file with pandas. It works on jupyter notebook (.ipynb) but doesnt work on python files (.py). I use the following code in my python file to import the csv file :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("business.csv")
print(df)
```

Yet,  I receive the following error :

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding Folder>  & 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '51427' '--' 'c:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding Folder\Python Projects\Pandas\csvReading.py'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding Folder\Python Projects\Pandas\csvReading.py", line 2, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("business.csv")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 605, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 457, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 814, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1045, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1862, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1357, in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 642, in get_handle
    handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'business.csv'
```

Can anyone help me out, I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Is the `business.csv` file in the same directory as the python script?

Comment: yes, it is in the same file directory as my python file

Comment: If it is in the same directory then check the name/spelling of file that you are importing......i.e maybe its `Business.csv`

Comment: The command line says your current directory is the "Coding Folder" directory, and the script is in "Coding Folder/Python Projects/Pandas"  If you know the file is the same folder as the script, you can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to find it.

Comment: I just tried it, but the only output I get from the system is this:

PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding Folder>  & 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\User\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '61750' '--' 'c:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding Folder\Python Projects\Pandas\csvReading.py'

Comment: @Tishan Christopher Prakash -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, I reproduced the problem you described. As people mentioned, the reason lies in the file path. The VS Code terminal is at the project folder level, therefore, it cannot find files in the inner folder in this folder.

Please refer to the solution as follows:

1. Since you are using debugging, you could use "`"cwd": "${fileDirname}",`" in "*launch.json*":

   [image]
2. If you want to click the run button on the top right of VS Code, we need to use `"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,` in "*settings.json*":

   [image]

They all make the terminal enter the folder where the currently executed file is located, so please make sure that the "csv" file and the "python" file are in the same folder.